# Is it a good idea to index a date column in descending order?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

In most of the tables having date column, we "would generally" query for the recent information.

Is it a good idea to index a date column "generally" in descending order?

Comment: If your queries are using the index, then yes it's a good idea (unless they slow down INSERTs to much)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: So you're saying "it depends, try it and profile the results".

Comment: @mu: more or less yes ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not familiar with Oracle's internals, but here's my understanding of how it works with Postgres:

Indexes are clustered for all intents and purposes. So if you they're ordered asc and new rows are always added towards the end of it (e.g. created_at, updated_at, billed_at, etc.), your new rows will be appended (or nearly so) rather than prepended (leading to disk page splits). This is faster.

Your query planner will happily read an index in reverse order. So if it's a single column index, either works -- use the most natural when it comes to how new rows are inserted in your use-case.

Where an index ordered in reverse order may become interesting, is when you've a multi-column index. Say, `(id, created_at desc)` in an audit log table. It's actually a bad example, but here's the point: if you're ordering by `id, created_at desc`, the index will be used as is.

Comment: Pretty much the same with Oracle. It can read the index in descending order, and ASC/DESC makes most sense when matching a multi-column index to the same multi-column order by

Answer (score 5):

Unless you see a significant performance improvement you *may* want to avoid descending indexes.  Descending indexes are actually function-based indexes, and have a few limitations.

For example, according to the [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5012.htm#sthref4514), unique descending indexes do not allow multiple nulls, and descending indexes are not used until you analyze the index and table.  (Although I am not able to reproduce the second limitation.)

Also, function-based indexes are a little different, and tend to break the index maintenance scripts that everybody writes.  This isn't a good reason to avoid them, just something to look out for.